# How to check if element has classes other than the specified classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have two classes which are dynamically applied to element on mouse event, say they are:

`classOne` and `classTwo`

How to check if the element which is receiving the mouse event has classes other than those two?

**HTML Example:**

```
<div>
    <span class="classOne classTwo">Element</span>
    <span class="classOne">Element</span>
    <span class="classTwo">Element</span>
    <span class="classOne classTwo otherClass">Element</span>
    <span class="classOne otherClass">Element</span>
    <span class="classTwo otherClass">Element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery allows you to use $(this);

Comment: is "classOne otherClass" possible?

Comment: @epascarello yes, it is possible.

Comment: And does that pass or fail? Do both have to be there?

Comment: @epascarello I am sorry, I don't get you...

Comment: Does "classOne otherClass" pass as having an "other" since it only has one of the two classes?

Comment: one of them is always being there, and both of them are sometimes there together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
 $('body').on('mouseover', 'span', function(){
    var spanclasses = $(this).attr('class').replace('classOne', '').replace('classTwo', '').trim();
    if(spanclasses.length)
    {
        alert('there is another class');
    }else{  
        alert('there is no other classes');
    }
 });
```

**UPDATE**

After receiving some feedback, here is the preferred way:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a8vkkqox/

```
 $('body').on('mouseover', 'span', function(){
      var span = $(this).clone().removeClass('classOne').removeClass('classTwo');
      if(span.attr('class').length)
      {
          alert('there is another class');
      }else{  
          alert('there is no other classes');
      }
 });
```

Comment: ideally there should be a reg exp for the replacement that has word boundries

Comment: @epascarello ideally loop through `this.classList` to determine whether there is element in this array, which doesn't equal to `classOne` and `classTwo`, or not should save the world, shouldn't it?

Comment: @erkaner OK, how about `<span class="classOne classTwo classOneclassTwo">`?

Comment: @SalmanA you can test your examples in mentioned demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a8vkkqox/. This example actually works correctly.

Comment: @Regent https://jsfiddle.net/a8vkkqox/1/  But this is really searching for the bug but who knows...

Comment: @A.Wolff yep, this is really counter-example.

Comment: @Regent Ya should be used on a clone instead

Comment: @erkaner For the second one, it should be e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/8qns4x0x/1/   `hover` isn't an event

Comment: @erkaner Ok now i think it's ok, really readable solution even this could be used to remove mutiple classes at once

Comment: `<span class="classOne classOne classTwo">Element</span>`

Comment: @SalmanA This isn't valid HTML markup as i'm aware of, i meant having same class on same element twice doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are after this:

```
var classes = ["classOne", "classTwo"];
$('div span').on('click', function (e) {
    var thisArray = this.classList;
    console.log(thisArray);
    $.each(thisArray, function (i, klas) {
        if ($.inArray(klas, classes) == -1) {
            alert('this element has the extra class.' + klas);
        }
    });
});
```

#### [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/wyjt8d00/)

Comment: Well, except the facts that I would prefer simple `for` instead of jQuery's `$.each()` and `if` instead of `$.inArray` in this case, this is what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is simple: grab the class attribute, extract class names and compare them against the whitelist:

```js
$(function() {
  var whitelist = ["classOne", "classTwo"];
  $("span").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var classNames = $this.attr("class").trim().split(/\s+/);
    var classOther = $.grep(classNames, function(className) {
      return $.inArray(className, whitelist) === -1;
    });
    if (classOther.length) {
      $this.css("border", "thick solid red");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="classOne classTwo">Element</span>
  <span class="classOne">Element</span>
  <span class="classTwo">Element</span>
  <span class="classOne classTwo otherClass">Element</span>
  <span class="classOne otherClass">Element</span>
  <span class="classTwo otherClass">Element</span>
  <span class="classOne classTwo classOneclassTwo">Element</span>
  <span class="classOne classOne">Element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems the most robust solution here

Answer (score 0):

The element with class other than `classOne` or `classTwo` will get red:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var classArr = that.attr('class').split(' ');
  for (i=0;i<classArr.length;i++) {
    if (classArr[i].indexOf('classOne') == -1 && classArr[i].indexOf('classTwo') == -1) {
      that.addClass('otherClass');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.otherClass { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="classOne classTwo">Element</span>
<span class="classOne">Element</span>
<span class="classTwo">Element</span>
<span class="classOne classTwo otherClass">Element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not what OP was asking

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.classOne.classTwo', function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
      var cls=$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
      if(cls.length>2) {
         alert(cls.length);
      }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/26ymg9za/1/)

If there are more than one element for this type you can use `.each()`

Comment: The question is not about whether element has more than two classes or not.

Comment: @Regent Can you find a case that this code will crash?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes how does this code help when you click at `<span class="classOne">Element</span>`?

Comment: well you use `is` or `filter`

Comment: how about when clicked?

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt but your code is still incorrect: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26ymg9za/2/).

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt I have shown you [counterexample](http://jsfiddle.net/26ymg9za/2/) where your code doesn't work. There is element `<span class="classOne otherClass">Element</span>`, but there is no `alert` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution. Script is triggered on mousehover.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("span").hover(function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass('otherClass')) {
     // do something 
     alert("otherClass");
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

**html**

```
 <div>
 <span class="classOne classTwo">Element</span>
 <span class="classOne">Element</span>
 <span class="classTwo">Element</span>
 <span class="classOne classTwo otherClass">Element</span>
 </div>
```

Don't forget to include js library.

Comment: OP was asking for `unknown` class, as i understood it. BTW, using hover `in/out` handler as no meaning here

Comment: Yes i know here is unknown class is otherClass and rest are coming dynamically. When you hover on last span my script is triggered.

Comment: But if you don't know the name of the class, **how** can you use: `$(this).hasClass('otherClass')` ???

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div > span').click(function(){
    var foo = $(this).attr('class');
    foo = foo.split(' ');
    var classOne = foo.indexOf("classOne");
    var classTwo = foo.indexOf("classTwo");
    if(classOne != -1 && classTwo != -1){
        alert('Both classes found');
    }
    else if(classOne != -1 && classTwo == -1){
        alert('classOne found');
    }
    else if(classOne == -1 && classTwo != -1){
        alert('classTwo found');
    }
    else{
        alert('none of classe found');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6k7y6h8/)**
**updated**

```
$('div > span').click(function(){
        var foo = $(this).attr('class');
        foo = foo.split(' ');
        var otherClass= foo.indexOf("otherClass");

        if(otherClass!= -1){
            alert('has otherClass');
        }

        else{
            alert('has no otherClass');
        }
});
```

**[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6k7y6h8/2/)**

Comment: The question is: **how to check if the element which is receiving the mouse event has class other than those two classes or not?**. Has. Other. Class.